# C Socket does not connect and returns exit value of 255

Tags: c, sockets

I have a piece of C code that should connect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and make a HTTP GET request, but when I run it, it stays on "Connecting.." for about 30 seconds before returning "Connection Failed" and an exit return value of 255. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8000
struct hostent *hostinfo;

int main(void) {
  int sock = 0, valread;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  char *hostname = "www.google.com";
  char *request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
  hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname);
  
  char *ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)hostinfo->h_addr_list[0]);

  char buffer[1024] = {0};
  printf("Creating socket...\n");
  if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
    return -1;
  }
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  printf("Checking address...\n");
  if(inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0){
    printf("\n Invalid IP/Address not supported \n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Connecting to host %s...\n", ip);
  if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    printf("\n Connection Failed \n");
    return -1;
  }
  send(sock, request, strlen(request), 0);
  printf("Message sent\n");
  valread = read(sock, buffer, 1024);
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Its been that kind of day :)  Deleted

Comment: Sounds like the connection failed. Does Google use port 8000?

Comment: Probably not directly related, but the 3rd argument to `connect` should be `sizeof struct sockaddr` rather than `sizeof  struct sockaddr_in`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That is wrong. `connect()` is expecting the *actual* size of the struct being passed in. So `sizeof struct sockaddr_in` is the correct value, since `serv_addr` is actually a `sockaddr_in` not a `sockaddr` (they just *happen* to be the same size on most systems).  If `serv_addr` were a `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6, then `sizeof struct sockaddr_in6` would need to be passed in instead. If you tried to pass in `sizeof struct sockaddr` when using a `sockaddr_in6`, `connect()` would fail with a different error.

Comment: @JuanR4140 You are not checking the return value of `gethostbyname()` for failure, or that it is actually an IPv4 address. There is no need to convert an `in_addr` to a `char*` (unless you are going to log it) just to convert it back to an `in_addr`, so just use the original as-is. If a system call fails (like `connect()`), you should log `errno` for troubleshooting (see `perror()`). In this case, `connect()` was likely reporting an `ECONNREFUSED` error due to the wrong `PORT` being used.

Comment: On a side note: Google uses HTTPS pretty exclusively nowadays, so sending a non-encrypted HTTP request to `www.google.com` on port 80 (`http:`) will not actually retrieve the page, it will return an HTTP redirect to `www.google.com` on port 443 (`https:`).  This code is not setup to handle HTTPS yet, so it won't actually be able to retrieve any content from anywhere on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two major problems.

- You use the wrong port. Use port `80` for `http`.
- Your `read` and `printf` is a dangerous combination that could easily cause access out of bounds (and *undefined behavior*). What you read from the socket will not be null terminated. You could instead do something like this:

  ```
  ...
  printf("Message sent\n");
  while((valread = read(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, valread, 1, stdout);
  }
  ```

  This will however block when everything has been read. See *non-blocking I/O* or consider using `select`, `epoll` or `poll` to wait for available data on sockets.

If you are only interested in getting the response and then disconnect, you could however use `Connection: close` to close the connection after the server has sent the response. Full code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 80

int main(void) {
  int sock = 0, valread;
  struct hostent *hostinfo;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  const char *hostname = "www.google.com";
  const char *request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: www.google.com\r\n"
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";   // <- added
  hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname);
  
  char *ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)hostinfo->h_addr_list[0]);

  char buffer[1024] = {0};
  printf("Creating socket...\n");
  if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
    return -1;
  }
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  printf("Checking address...\n");
  if(inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0){
    printf("\n Invalid IP/Address not supported \n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Connecting to host %s...\n", ip);
  if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    perror("connect()");
    return -1;
  }
  send(sock, request, strlen(request), 0);
  printf("Message sent\n");
  while((valread = read(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, valread, 1, stdout);
  }
}
```

Comment: Re "*This will however block when everything has been read.*",  when everything *received* has been read. It will unblock when new stuff arrives or when the connection is closed, and the loop will be exited when the connection is closed. This is fine here. No need for `select`/`epoll`/`poll`.

Comment: @ikegami I just noticed that OP made `valread` an `int` instead of `ssize_t` but size the max length that can be read is 1024 it should be safe since it checks `> 0`. My hints about using `select` or similar was if the connection is to be kept. My suggested code however tells the server to disconnect so no, no `select` needed.

Comment: Re "*it should be safe since it checks `> 0`.*", Overlooked that! Comment deleted.

Comment: Re "*My hints about using `select` or similar was if the connection is to be kept.*", `select` is not needed to "keep the connection". `select`/`epoll`/`poll` is only needed if you want parallelism (e.g. to read from two sockets at once), which isn't needed here.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I described that badly. One other feature that one could use `select` for is the timeout.